# Providing Wireless at event swamped by other wireless traffic

Tags: wifi

I had the task of managing the I.T at a Expo event my company exhibitted at. This involved (relative to this question) streaming videos from a locally hosted server (HTTP) to 8 IPads wirelessly. We wrote the IPad app and in testing everything constantly worked perfectly. The exact same hardware and infrastructure we tested on in the office was used on site.

When I got to site on setup day, I quickly discovered that the amount of (other) wireless AP's was massive. Despite the IPads having a connection and full signal to my AP, the data transfer was so slow that the streaming wouldn't work. Even just showing an image via the web browser on the local server was slow to load. 
Distance to the AP from the IPads was no more than 10 meters at most. The closest was 2 meters.

The issue also occurred via my laptop, to rule out some Ipad related issue.

I tried fixing the AP to a channel without success.

I resolved the issue by re-writing the app to embed the videos locally.

however, what did I do wrong? how should I have approached this from the start to take into consideration what I suspect is just mass competition for the same 2.4Ghz frequencies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wifi doesn't use any sensible type of collision detection, and there are only 3 non overlapping channels. It is notoriously bad for something like an event with lots of devices in an open area.  It can be mitigated slightly by very strict coordination of APs and their channels but its unlikely that you'll be able to just turn up and stream video reliably.  Until it becomes more widespread using 5.8Ghz might be less congested.